# Подключить Qt библиотеки в Visual Studio для UE4

Tags: qt, visual-studio, unreal-engine-4

Как можно подключить Qt библиотеки в Visual studio для Unreal engine 4?

Как я понял, у Unreal engine 4 своя система сборки через файл C# - *.Build.cs и поэтому через свойства проекта не получится подключить библиотеки, там просто отсутствует вкладка "C++" которая описана во всех подобных туториалах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке указать через файл *.Build.cs путь к библиотеки и подключаемую .dll проект не собирается и ругается на эту dll.

```
PrivateIncludePaths.Add("c:/Qt/5.14.2/msvc2017_64/include/");
PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add("c:/Qt/5.14.2/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Core.dll");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это лог сборки в UE4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно указать пути к файлам .h, .lib, .dll в связке VS/UE4?

Comment: Вы к шарповому коду хотите подключить нативные плюсове бибиотеки?

Comment: У Вас же шарп, значит есть winform

Comment: Ну программирование в UE4 происходит на C++ и там по скриншоту видно, что при сборке проекта сам UE4 прикрутил cpp и h файлы, поэтому да, я хочу прикрутить плюсовые библиотеки Qt.Мне из qt не интерфейс нужен, а библиотеки по работе с Android, а если точнее то intent

Comment: Дайте мне возможность переварить. Что бы использовать intent для андроида, Вы хотите прицепить целый Qt? Если я правильно понимаю документацию, то blueprint имеет доступ к intent - https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/GoogleVRHMD/GetIntentData/index.html - а значит и плюсовый код тоже.

Comment: На intent у Qt очень много примеров и документация есть, а вот UE4 скупа на это дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, чтоб добавить Qt библиотеки в UE4. Покажу на примере Qt5Core.dll/lib

1. Вам нужен msvc2017_64 который указывается при установке QtCreator и установленная поверх Visual studio расширение Qt VS Tools
2. Создать проект UE4 с использованием C++
3. В Корневой папке проекта создать дополнительные папки
   У меня в данном случае они указаны вот так:

[Корневая папка вашего проекта]/ThirdParty/Qt/Includes/QtCore

[Корневая папка вашего проекта]/ThirdParty/Qt/Libraries/Win64

4. Из корневой папки Qt перенести нужные файлы:

В моём случае находим в C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore

и перетаскиваем все файлы в [Корневая папка вашего проекта]/ThirdParty/Qt/Includes/QtCore
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\lib находим Qt5Core.lib и Qt5Cored.lib

и копируем в [Корневая папка вашего проекта]/ThirdParty/Qt/Libraries/Win64

В папке C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\bin находим Qt5Core.dll и Qt5Cored.lib

и копируем в [Корневая папка вашего проекта]/ThirdParty/Qt/Libraries/Win64

5. Открываем ваш проект через visual studio и находим файл [Имя вашего проекта].build.cs
   и меняем его. В данном случае у меня проект называется "InfProject2" измените на собственное имя проекта.

// Copyright 1998-2019 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

```
using System.IO;
using UnrealBuildTool;

public class InfProject2 : ModuleRules
{
    private string ModulePath
    {
        get { return ModuleDirectory; }
    }

    private string ThirdPartyPath
    {
        get { return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "../../ThirdParty/")); }
    }

    public InfProject2(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)    
    {
        PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;
    
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" , "RHI", "RenderCore" });

        PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] {  });
                
        PrivateIncludePaths.Add("D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.24/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Public/");

        LoadQt(Target);

        /* 
        //Uncomment if you are using Slate UI
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Slate", "SlateCore" });

        // Uncomment if you are using online features
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");

        // To include OnlineSubsystemSteam, add it to the plugins section in your uproject file with the Enabled attribute set to true
        */
    }


    public bool LoadQt(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target)
    {
        // Start OpenCV linking here!
        bool isLibrarySupported = false;

        // Create OpenCV Path 
        string QtPath = Path.Combine(ThirdPartyPath, "Qt");

        // Get Library Path 
        string LibPath = "";
        bool isdebug = Target.Configuration == UnrealTargetConfiguration.Debug;

        if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Win64)
        {
            LibPath = Path.Combine(QtPath, "Libraries", "Win64");
            isLibrarySupported = true;
        }
        else
        {
            string Err = string.Format("{0} dedicated server is made to depend on {1}. We want to avoid this, please correct module dependencies.", Target.Platform.ToString(), this.ToString()); System.Console.WriteLine(Err);
        }

        if (isLibrarySupported)
        {
            //Add Include path 
            PublicIncludePaths.AddRange(new string[] { Path.Combine(QtPath, "Includes") });

            // Add Library Path 
            PublicLibraryPaths.Add(LibPath);

            //Add Static Libraries
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add("Qt5Core.lib");

            //Add Dynamic Libraries
            PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("Qt5Core.dll");
        }

        PublicDefinitions.Add(string.Format("WITH_QT_BINDING={0}", isLibrarySupported ? 1 : 0));

        return isLibrarySupported;
    }
}
```

6. Создайте Новый класс C++ через Unreal engine 4 и подключите библиотеку в .cpp файл созданного класса

   #include "QtCore/qstring.h"

в конструкторе указываем

```
AOwlActorAndroid::AOwlActorAndroid()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    QString str = "QT";
    GEngine -> AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, str.toStdString().c_str());
}
```

И смотрим на результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше информации можно узнать здесь https://www.ue4community.wiki/Legacy/Detailed_Account_Of_Integrating_OpenCV_Into_UE4_With_VS2017